# PHP Article Slug instead of ID

Tags: php, mysql, url, parameter-passing, slug

so I've saved an article slug to my database and usually I would filter my pages with the `art_id` like so,

```
$sql_articles = "SELECT * FROM app_articles WHERE art_id=".$_GET['art_id'];
$result_articles = query($sql_articles);
```

and I pass would pass the `art_id` through the url with a link like so

```
<a href="index.php?art_id=<?php echo $article['art_id']; ?>">
```

And I'm wondering how I can pass the `art_slug` instead of the `art_id` so my URL would be like `www.site.com/index.php/lorem-ipsum-slug` and it would display the article thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it looks like you have an SQL injection possibility. Google it.

Secondly you'll need to create an `art_slug` column in your database. After it you should be able to do the following:

```
$sql_articles = "SELECT * FROM app_articles WHERE art_id=".$_GET['art_slug'];
$result_articles = query($sql_articles);
```

and you'll be able to pass the art_slug through the url with a link like so

```
<a href="content.php?art_slug=<?php echo $article['art_slug']; ?>">
```

---

You've updated the question and things got more clear. You may be interested in [rewriting your URL on the server side](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). The given documentation is for Apache, but this functionality exists in all major webservers.

Comment: Thanks yeah I already have that set up but my URL is like `content.php?art_slug=lorme-ipsum` but I see a lot of sites like stackoverflow and their URLS are like `content.php/lorem-ipsum`

Answer (score 1):

The same way you would pass an ID.

```
$sql_articles = "SELECT * FROM app_articles WHERE art_slug=".$_GET['art_slug'];
$result_articles = query($sql_articles);
```

and

`<a href="content.php?art_slug=<?php echo $article['art_slug']; ?>">`

You should sanitize your variables rather than using it from $_GET directly, because it makes you vulnerable to SQL injection attack.